# Excel output file saving error: 255 characters since it exceeds Excel's limit for URLS

Tags: python, excel, xlsxwriter

I am having an issue where the data is not being saved in excel due to exceeding limit of 255 characters of URL value. I am curious to know the solution to this specific problem for my code. Hope someone could suggest and help:

Below is my piece of xlsxwriter code in python:

```
import xlsxwriter
from openpyxl import load_workbook

workbook =xlsxwriter.Workbook('Output.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

row = 0
col = 0
data = []

url = "http://ec.europa.eu/environment/ets/ohaDetails.do?returnURL=&languageCode=en&accountID=&registryCode=&buttonAction=all&action=&account.registryCode=&accountType=&identifierInReg=&accountHolder=&primaryAuthRep=&installationIdentifier=&installationName=&accountStatus=&permitIdentifier=&complianceStatus=&mainActivityType=-1&searchType=oha&backList=%3C%C2%A0Back&resultList.currentPageNumber=1007&selectedPeriods="

data.append(url)
worksheet.write_row(row, col, tuple(data))
workbook.close()
```

Build Result:

```
UserWarning: Ignoring URL 'http://ec.europa.eu/environment/ets/ohaDetails.do?returnURL=&languageCode=en&accountID=&registryCode=&buttonAction=all&action=&account.registryCode=&accountType=&identifierInReg=&accountHolder=&primaryAuthRep=&installationIdentifier=&installationName=&accountStatus=&permitIdentifier=&complianceStatus=&mainActivityType=-1&searchType=oha&backList=%3C%C2%A0Back&resultList.currentPageNumber=1007&selectedPeriods=' with link or location/anchor > 255 characters since it exceeds Excel's limit for URLS
  force_unicode(url))
```

Comment: How about using a URL shortener?

Answer (score 0):

> I am curious to know the solution to this specific problem for my code.

No. This is an Excel [limitation](https://www.google.com/search?&q=Excel%20255%20character%20url%20). It only allows urls up to 255 characters!

Comment: Can you suggest how to implement it?

Comment: The `HYPERLINK()` formula workaround I suggested (and now deleted) doesn't work since the formula also only takes strings <= 255 characters. As such, I don't have any suggestions on how to workaround this Excel issue.