# exceeding URL limit after scrapy warning

Tags: python, scrapy, xlsxwriter

I got this when the scrapy spider was done, and the program was writing the data to an excel file using <s>`openpyxl`</s>`xlsxwriter`, however, in the warning it says `xlsx.writer` which I don't use, the reason this a problem is because Some of the data was not written and was skipped.
here is jist of code:

```
import scrapy,csv,requests
import re,json
from openpyxl import Workbook
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from json.decoder import JSONDecodeError
from openpyxl.utils.dataframe import dataframe_to_rows
#spidercode 
df = pd.DataFrame(spider.list_of_items)
df.to_excel("{}.xlsx".format(file_name))
```

---

```
2019-05-16 10:50:07 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
2019-05-16 10:50:15 [py.warnings] WARNING: C:\Users\test\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\xlsxwriter\worksheet.py:915:
UserWarning: Ignoring URL 'https://www.target.com/p/nfl-indianapolis-colts-northwest-draft-full-queen-comforter-set/-/A-53033602?ref=tgt_soc_0000059195_pd&afid=pin_ao&cpng=DR_PSA_Sports&fndsrc=bcm&campaignid=626738629371&adgroupid=2680061765888&product_partition_id=2954942580838&device=m&pp=1' 
with link or location/anchor > 255 characters since it exceeds Excel's limit for URLs force_unicode(url))
```

What I want is a fix for this or a way to write the row without URL if this warning happens to at least get the rest of the row.

Comment: Please, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Another question related to this one: https://stackoverflow.com/q/54135602/939364

Comment: Pandas uses xlsxwriter by default.

Comment: @CharlieClark is there a way to solve this? . I know now it is an excel issue so the solution is to cut (shorten) the link, or spread it over two cells right?

Comment: @Gallaecio I am sorry I can't share more code,the spider is 800 line step by step. I shared what I believed was enough to solve

Comment: When using `xlsxwriter` as the ExcelWriter engine you can turn off the automatic conversion of url strings to Excel urls using the`strings_to_urls` constructor option. See [this section](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_pandas.html#passing-xlsxwriter-constructor-options-to-pandas) of the XlsxWriter docs.

Comment: I never suggested you share your original code, I suggest you share the shortest code example possible that can be used to reproduce your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your url (266 symbols):`'https://www.target.com/p/nfl-indianapolis-colts-northwest-draft-full-queen-comforter-set/-/A-53033602?ref=tgt_soc_0000059195_pd&afid=pin_ao&cpng=DR_PSA_Sports&fndsrc=bcm&campaignid=626738629371&adgroupid=2680061765888&product_partition_id=2954942580838&device=m&pp=1'`

consists of 2 parts:

- actual url (101 symbols):
  [`https://www.target.com/p/nfl-indianapolis-colts-northwest-draft-full-queen-comforter-set/-/A-53033602`](https://www.target.com/p/nfl-indianapolis-colts-northwest-draft-full-queen-comforter-set/-/A-53033602)
- and it's query params (after `?` symbol in url): 
  `ref=tgt_soc_0000059195_pd
  afid=pin_ao&cpng=DR_PSA_Sports
  fndsrc=bcm
  campaignid=626738629371
  adgroupid=2680061765888
  product_partition_id=2954942580838
  device=m
  pp=1`

If query params data doesn't have any practical value - you can simply cut it off from original url and avoid excel 255 symbols link restriction:

```
....
#your spidercode 
for item in spider.list_of_items:
    #url = item[url_index] # if each item is a list or tuple
    #url = item[url] # if each item is a dict
    if "?" in url:
        url = url.split("?")[0]
df = pd.DataFrame(spider.list_of_items)
df.to_excel("{}.xlsx".format(file_name))
```